# After Android Studio Update Bumblebee, The project is not a Gradle-based project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I had fully working Flutter android app. Got an Android Studio update message and updated. Now it shows "The project is not a Gradle-based project" it doesnt detected as flutter dart app. And can't run anymore. How can i fix? build gradle is already exist on android folder and was fully working. Latest Android Studio update caused the problem.

**Note: I downloaded previous version (arctic fox) of Android Studio and everything works. Something is wrong in latest version.**

Answer (score 1):

I lost an entire morning yesterday after updating to Bumblebee. It broke my Flutter project so badly. I couldn't do Android builds or iOS builds anymore (it was insisting I didn't have cocoa pods installed even though I did  - even flutter doctor confirmed I did) and after spending hours trying to fix it all I gave up and went back to Arctic Fox and everything was fine again.

I'm glad it's not just me that's had Flutter problems with Bumblebee.

I suggest rolling back to Arctic Fox and waiting for the next patch release before trying to upgrade again.

As an aside... I'm on an M1 Mac, so I don't know whether there's some compatibility issue with that.

You may wish to try uninstalling and reinstalling your Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio, but that didn't work for me.